# singularities of the theta divisor $\Theta$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

By $\Theta_{sing}$ we denote the singularities of the theta 
divisor $\Theta$ of the Jacobian variety $J(R)$ of a compact Riemann surface 
R of genus $g\ge 4$. Then 
$$
\text{dim} \Theta_{sing}=
\{\begin{array}{l}g-4\, \, \, \, \,\text{if $R$ is non-hyperelliptic,} \\g-3\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \text{if $R$ is hyperelliptic.}\end{array}
$$
This result is due to Andreotti and Mayer. For $ g = 2 $, we have that the divisor $\Theta$ is smooth. My question is in gelation at $ g = 3 $. What can you say when $ g = 3 $? Is the divisor $\Theta$ smooth too or $\Theta_{sing}\not=\emptyset$ ?

Would the following statement be correct?

Considering $g = 3$ ...

Marten's Theorem (Geometry of Algebraic Curves
Volume I, Arbarello, E., Cornalba, M., Griffiths, P., Harris, page 191) + (4.5) Corollary (from the same book, page 190)    $\Longrightarrow $ dim$(W_{2})_{sing}=W^{1}_{2}=0$. So $\Theta$ is smooth for $g = 3$.

Comment: dim zero means it is a finite set of points, not an empty set.  and recall that a point of this set is a line bundle of degree 2 with 2 sections, which does happen when R is hyperelliptic.  Just take a double cover of the line branched at 8 points, say y^2 = x^8-1.  So the same dimensionality result holds that you stated for g ≥ 4. Hence for g=3, Theta has a singularity if and only if R is hyperelliptic.

Comment: If you look at pages 201, 212 of A-M's paper, you will see the explanation for the reason the singular locus of theta has dimension g-3 in the hyperelliptic case, i.e. that the general such singular point has the form: the g(1,2) + g-3 general points.  This holds for g ≥ 3, although they do not say that. I.e. this argument assumes that g-3 ≥ 0. http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_1967_3_21_2_189_0/